# Erlang ETS tables versus message passing: Optimization concerns?

Tags: process, erlang, ets

I'm coming into an existing (game) project whose server component is written entirely in erlang.  At times, it can be excruciating to get a piece of data from this system (I'm interested in how many widgets player 56 has) from the process that owns it.  Assuming I can find the process that owns the data, I can pass a message to that process and wait for it to pass a message back, but this does not scale well to multiple machines and it kills response time.

I have been considering replacing many of the tasks that exist in this game with a system where information that is frequently accessed by multiple processes would be stored in a protected ets table.  The table's owner would do nothing but receive update messages (the player has just spent five widgets) and update the table accordingly.  It would catch all exceptions and simply go on to the next update message.  Any process that wanted to know if the player had sufficient widgets to buy a fooble would need only to peek at the table.  (Yes, I understand that a message might be in the buffer that reduces the number of widgets, but I have that issue under control.)

I'm afraid that my question is less of a question and more of a request for comments.  I'll upvote anything that is both helpful and sufficiently explained or referenced.

What are the likely drawbacks of such an implementation?  I'm interested in the details of lock contention that I am likely to see in having one-writer-multiple-readers, what sort of problems I'll have distributing this across multiple machines, and especially: input from people who've done this before.

Answer (score 8):

first of all, default ETS behaviour is consistent, as you can see by documentation: [Erlang ETS](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html).
It provides atomicity and isolation, also multiple updates/reads if done in the same function (remember that in Erlang a function call is roughly equivalent to a reduction, the unit of measure Erlang scheduler uses to share time between processes, so a multiple function ETS operation could possibly be split in more parts creating a possible race condition).

If you are interested in multiple nodes ETS architecture, maybe you should take a look to mnesia if you want an OOTB multiple nodes concurrency with ETS: [Mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html).
(hint: I'm talking specifically of ram_copies tables, add_table_copy and change_config methods).

That being said, I don't understand the problem with a process (possibly backed up by a not named ets table).
I explain better: the main problem with your project is the first, basic assumption.
It's simple: you don't have a single writing process!

Every time a player takes an object, hits a player and so on, it calls a non side effect free function updating game state, so even if you have a single process managing game state, he must also tells other player clients 'hey, you remember that object there? Just forget it!'; this is why the main problem with many multiplayer games is lag: lag, when networking is not a main issue, is many times due to blocking send/receive routines.

From this point of view, using directly an ETS table, using a persistent table, a process dictionary (BAD!!!) and so on is the same thing, because you have to consider synchronization issues, like in objects oriented programming languages using shared memory (Java, everyone?).

In the end, you should consider just ONE main concern developing your application: consistency.
After a consistent application has been developed, only then you should concern yourself with performance tuning.

Hope it helps!

Note: I've talked about something like a MMORPG server because I thought you were talking about something similar.

Answer (score 7):

An ETS table would not solve your problems in that regard. Your code (that wants to get or set the player widget count) will always run in a process and the data must be copied there.

Whether that is from a process heap or an ETS table makes little difference (that said, reading from ETS is often faster because it's well optimized and doesn't perform any other work than getting and setting data). Especially when getting the data from a remote node. For multple readers ETS is most likely faster since a process would handle the requests sequentially.

What would make a difference however, is if the data is cached on the local node or not. That's where self replicating database systems, such as Mnesia, Riak or CouchDB, comes in. Mnesia is in fact implemented using ETS tables.

As for locking, the latest version of Erlang comes with enhancements to ETS which enable multiple readers to simultaneously read from a table plus one writer that writes. The only locked element is the row being written to (thus better concurrent performance than a normal process, if you expect many simultaneous reads for one data point).

Note however, that all interaction with ETS tables is non-transactional! That means that you cannot rely on writing a value based on a previous read because the value might have changed in the meantime. Mnesia handles that using transactions. You can still use the `dirty_*` functions in Mneisa to squeeze out near-ETS performance out of most operations, if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have a bunch of things that can happen at any time, and you need to aggregate the data in a safe, uniform way. Take a look at the [Generic Event](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/events.html) behavior. I'd recommend using this to create an event server, and have all these processes share this information via events to your server, at that point you can choose to log it or store it somewhere (like an ETS table). As an aside, ETS tables are not good for peristent data like  how many "widgets" a player has - consider [Mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html), or an excellent crash only db like [CouchDB](http://code.google.com/p/ecouch/). Both of these replicate very well across machines.

---

You bring up lock contention - you shouldn't have any locks. Messages are processed in a synchronous order as they are received by each process. In fact, the entire point of the message passing semantics built into the language is to avoid shared-state concurrency.

To summarize, normally you communicate with messages, from process to process. This is hairy for you, because you need information from processes scattered all over the place, so my recommendation for you is based of the idea of concentrating all information that is "interesting" outside of the originating processes into a single, real-time source.

Comment: The lock contention question is in regard to the implementation of erlang's ets tables.  If I have 2500 processes that might read a table and one process that can ever write to it, there will eventually be a moment when a reader and a writer are trying to reference the same data and ets has to resolve that issue.  I would certainly never start manually locking and unlocking data in erlang.  I'm not even certain if that's possible, given the immutability of data.